# Как передать нужную часть jsp/html страницы на другую html страницу c помощью Ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Допустим есть **index.html**, он вызывается с помощью контроллера:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getIndex() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        return mav;
    }
```

После загрузки этой страницы, допустим, у меня там есть кнопка при нажатии на которую вызывается метод:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getPage() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "getPage",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#pageContainer").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Далее Ajax-запрос вызывает еще один мой контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("test/page");
        return mav;
    }
```

Но контроллер getPage() возвращает целый html / jsp документ в data. Как мне переписать контроллер getPage() что бы он возвращал не весь файл page а нужную его часть?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос  код страницы "test/page", и укажите какую часть хотите вернуть.

Comment: Любой html код который посчитаете нужным.

Comment: Тогда удалите лишний код на странице, оставить нужно только содержимое тега body, а сам этот тег тоже удалите.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось.

Comment: Добавил как ответ, пометьте как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас такая страница jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Содержимое страницы</div>
<div>Еще данные</div>
</body>
</html>
```

то из нее удалите лишний код, и оставьте содержимое тега body, чтоб получилось так:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<div>Содержимое страницы</div>
<div>Еще данные</div>
```